# Usage of '' to mean "ditto"

Tags: punctuation

The NOAD reports that *''* (two single quotation marks) is a symbol used to mean *ditto*.

When is it used? Should it be used to replace the same word that appears in the same position but in the previous line?

> I always thought it could be a dog.
>   I then discovered it is all but a ''.

Comment: @Billare - your edit changed the question (incorrectly) and besides that I'm not sure it adds much to visit quotation marks upon questions as I see you've been doing in the past few minutes.

Comment: @Ed Guiness Not using quotation marks changes the semantic meaning of the questions being asked, which is why they recommended as a general usage rule.  Additionally, it helps me, and others, discern exactly what is being asked at a glance.

Comment: @Billare technically you may have a point, do you think in practice it matters?

Comment: "Should it be used to replace the same word that appears in the same position but in the previous line?" — Yes, the same position is important. It can even be used to replace more than one word.

Comment: @Ed Guiness Yes, I think it matters in practice.  That's why I do it, because I care over proper formatting -- though not enough to get into an argument or an edit war over it, if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: @Billare http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @Ed Guiness Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **[ditto mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark)** is a typographic symbol that should be confined to lists, and works best when a non-proportional or monospaced font is used, else it may not appear in the right place.

Comment: Agreed. I use it most in handwriting.

Comment: It was traditionally used in ledgers, yes?

Comment: I've seen it particularly in 19th century censuses, where the address and other data was repeated for the separate lines for individuals.

Comment: I wouldn't use quotation marks to mean "ditto the above" except in my own notes or shorthand. With modern word processing and formatting capabilities to do so would be unprofessional and serve to confuse.

Comment: In handwriting, when using it to mean several words are replaced, I use a horizontal line that stretches the span of repeated words with a ditto in the middle:   --------''-------

Comment: It's used quite often, but only for columnular data.

Comment: And with Unicode, you don't need to use '' for the ditto mark, you can use 〃.